# what is the `deprecation of the balances.transfer` meaning at Polkadot v0.9.42?

Tags: polkadot-js

The link: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases

The message: `Please note the upcoming deprecation of the balances.transfer call.`

What is the `Balances::transfer becomes Balances::transfer_allow_death` meaning?

Should I use it like this?

```
const { tx } = expandMetadata(this.api.registry, this.api.runtimeMetadata);
const methodFunction2 = tx['balances']['transfer_allow_death'];
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.

> Some renaming:
>
> - Balances::set_balance becomes Balances::force_set_balance
> - Balances::transfer becomes Balances::transfer_allow_death
>
> In the latter case, since ecosystem tooling largely depends on using
> transfer, a compatibility stub for transfer remains, however this
> naming is DEPRECATED and ecosystem tools should move over to using
> transfer_allow_death within 3 months at which point the transfer alias
> will be removed.

Taken from the PR description:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951

Please read the PR as there is a wealth of information.